# Star topology possible?

Tags: nodeos

I'm currently constructing multiple nodeos topology. 
What I have succeeded is a chain topology like followings

nodeos1 - nodeos2 - nodeos3 - nodeos4

How can I construct a star topology in such a way that nodeos2~4 connect to nodeos1?

I was able to connect the second nodeos to the first nodeos with --p2p-peer-address option. 
However, when I exeucte the 3rd nodeos with --p2p-peer-address to the first nodeos, it fails. 
Instead, if I set --p2p-peer-address to the 2nd nodeos, it worked.

Comment: Fails how? what is the error message? Try to add more info so people can better help you. We're not seeing what's on your screen, so you have to invest more in explaining what exactly you did and what happened.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. 
I added the following option for nodeos execution. 
--p2p-max-nodes-per-host 10

Originally, the default value was 1, so nodeos3 and nodeos4 couldn't connect to nodeos1.

Comment: nodeos -e --producer-name eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::net_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --access-control-allow-origin=* --http-validate-host=false --http-server-address 0.0.0.0:8888 --p2p-listen-endpoint 0.0.0.0:9876 --p2p-max-nodes-per-host 10